# Is it possible to create schema references that are sometimes nullable and sometimes not?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a schema that re-uses an object type quite a lot, and I'd like to extract that type into `$defs`. However, I sometimes need it to be nullable, and sometimes not. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Example schema with all the duplication:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type: "object",
      "properties: {
        "a": { "type": "string" },
        "b": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        "c": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
      },
      "required": ["a"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "bar": {
      "type: "object",
      "properties: {
        "a": { "type": "string" },
        "b": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        "c": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
      },
      "required": ["a"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "baz": {
      "type: ["object", "null"],
      "properties: {
        "a": { "type": "string" },
        "b": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        "c": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
      },
      "required": ["a"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

I can get *almost* all the way with something like

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "$ref": "#/$defs/abc" },
    "bar": { "$ref": "#/$defs/abc" },
    "baz": { "$ref": "#/$defs/abc" }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "abc": {
      "type: "object",
      "properties: {
        "a": { "type": "string" },
        "b": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        "c": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
      },
      "required": ["a"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

however, now `baz` is not nullable. How can I achieve maximum re-usability of the properties definitions etc, but with variable nullability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nulls are weird in JSON, so there's a little ambiguity here. In most languages, null means there is nothing there. In JSON, the equivalent is "undefined". A value is undefined if it doesn't exist in the JSON. Null in JSON is a different concept where the value exists and it's type is "null". The "null" type consists of the singleton value `null` and is not equivalent to undefined.

So, when you talk about nullability, I'm assuming you mean "null" or undefined because that's how your schemas are written. If you have a choice, I'd recommend not to use `null` in JSON and leave out values that have no value instead.

---

JSON Schema doesn't have a way to remove constraints, so you have to define your definitions a little leaner to facilitate composition. `"type": ["object", "null"]` is sugar for `"anyOf: [{ "type": "object" }, { "type": "null" }]`. Once you break that down, you end up with a small enough unit to facilitate the composition you require.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "$ref": "#/$defs/abc" },
    "bar": { "$ref": "#/$defs/abc" },
    "baz": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/$defs/abc" },
        { "type": "null" }
      ]
    }
  },

  "$defs": {
    "abc": {
      "type: "object",
      "properties: {
        "a": { "type": "string" },
        "b": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        "c": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
      },
      "required": ["a"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For my use case, I actually _do_ want to validate that all the keys are present, and (sometimes) allow their values to be `null`... but thanks for the expansion on `null`/`undefined` anyway! I think this `anyOf` approach will probably work well - will immediately test it out!